# Time taken to receive ESTA approval

Tags: visas, us-visa-waiver-program

How many days/hour does it take to receive an ESTA authorisation since placing online application?

Answer (score 5):

Most ESTA applications are processed in seconds and result in **Authorization Approved** or **Travel Not Authorized**. If your application is marked **Authorization Pending** then it can take up to 72 hours for your application to be processed.

You should check the ESTA web site for the current status of your application, and if it is pending, continue to check periodically.

Source: [US Customs and Border Protection](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1143/~/how-do-i-know-if-my-esta-application-was-approved)

Comment: It might be worth noting that the careful planner will apply for ESTA authorization a few *months* before the trip, before buying tickets, to allow for the possibility that ESTA will be denied and a visa application will be needed.  I doubt many people plan so carefully, of course, and for the vast majority it works just fine like that, but for anyone with a critical trip planned, it is better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: Last one took a minute or 2 and I got worried as they've always been instant. Usually nothing to worry about.